# Zero or non zero electrical potential energy of the system

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Say you have this scenario:

[image]

and you wanted to find the electric potential energy of the +q charge

Now if you were to find the potential energy of +Q and +q system and add that to the potential energy of the -Q and +q system like scalars you would get:

> $ \frac {kqQ} {d} + \frac {kq(-Q)} {d}$

which is equal to 0

But if you were to calculate the electric field at where +q is, you would get

> $ \sqrt{{(\frac {kQ} {d^2})^2} + {(\frac {k(-Q)} {d^2})^2}} $

which equals

> $ \sqrt2 \frac {kQ} {d^2} $

And the electric potential at that point would be

> $ \sqrt2 \frac {kQd} {d^2} $

which is

> $ \sqrt2 \frac {kQ} {d} $

then if you were to multiply q to the electric potential you would get the electrical potential energy, which is:

> $ \sqrt2 \frac {kQq} {d} $

So how can this be both zero and non-zero? Both methods seems right to me I am not sure how to approach this mathematically because they both seem right, but I still cannot understand this question intuitively as well:

If you were to move the charge from the bottom left of the screen to where it is on the picture, it would take 0 work as the attraction from the -Q charge will be the same as the repulsion from the +Q charge. Since 0 work is done, electrical potential energy is 0

Now if you were to just place the -q charge where it is and let go, it will accelerate to the bottom right of the picture. Since it accelerated on its own, there must be energy causing the acceleration, which would be the electrical potential energy.

So which one would be right? zero electrical potential energy or non zero?

Also, I know this looks like a homework question but I assure you it is not. I encountered this on my midterm yesterday. But if it still counts as homework, let me know and I'll add the tag, or you can edit the tag of the question.

Comment: There a several problems in what your doing. 1) the electrical field is not a scalar and the absolute value of the vector (which is what you compute) is of little interest here 2) even if E were what you are saying, that does not imply that the potential Phi=E*d (which is what you compuite). The field is the gradient of the potential, meaning you have to integrate in some fashion to get the potential from the field, and thus you cannot do this knowing the field at only one point. The potential approach is way easier here (you still have to do it right, though)

Comment: @Bort I see. Thanks for the input. Are you saying the potential energy is 0? If that is so, why would it move if you let go of the +q charge? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential energy is the integral of the force from infinity to the position of the charge:

$$ V(\mathbf{x}) = \int_\infty^\mathbf{x} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x}') \cdot d\mathbf{x}' $$

where you need to note that both $\mathbf{F}$ and $d\mathbf{x}'$ are vectors so the direction of the force matters.

The easy way to do this is to note that the net force on $q$ is in the direction top left to bottom right (i.e. parallel to the line joining $+Q$ and $-Q$. If you move your charge $q$ out to infinity along a line bottom left to top right then $\mathbf{F}$ and $d\mathbf{x}'$ are always perpendicular so $\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{x}' = 0$ and therefore $V = 0$.

You can take any path you want to do the integral, but any other path will have $\mathbf{F}$ changing direction as you move.